# Can I access the Messenger from the IoC Container?

Tags: mvvm, inversion-of-control, ioc-container, messenger

I'm new with IoC, and i'm trying to follow best practices in applying it.
I have a ListViewModel from where i want to create a new EditViewModel that accepts the injection of the object that has to be modfied.

I thought the solution could be sending a message containing this object to the IoC Container, that will pass it to the EditViewModel.

Can I do it? Is there any better way?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your view model to create other view models, then you want to create a view model factory. Your `ListViewModel` would take this view model factory as a dependency (via constructor injection for example), then when it wanted to create an edit view model, it could do:

```
var editViewModel = this.EditViewModelFactory.Create(modelToEdit);
```

or

```
var editViewModel = this.EditViewModelFactory.Create();
editViewModel.SetModel(modelToEdit);
```

You want the edit view model factory to be resolved via your IoC container. Containers such as Castle Windsor and Ninject allow automatic factory registration. In this case, you only define the interface for the factory, and the container actually instantiates a type that implements this interface for you.

You certainly don't want your application talking to your container via a mediator.

Comment: Thank you very much!!
Just another question: does the IoC register the factored instance? (Usually I mean)

Comment: You register your dependencies with the IoC container, so this will include your factory classes and view model classes that the factories return. If you are using Castle Windsor then have a look at the Typed Factory Facility examples, if you are using Ninject there is a factory extension available.

Comment: Can the Create method of the factory class register the created instance in the container?

Comment: Which IoC container are you using? Normally your factory will want to create seperate instances of your view models, so you would register the view model type that the factory creates against the service, not an instance of the view model. So for example, you would register EditViewModelFactory against IEditViewModelFactory (as a singleton) and EditViewModel as a transient registration. Of course, if you're doing this a lot, you might want to create a generic IViewModelFactory<T> type.

Comment: In my situation I have the MainWindow vith the ListViewModel, and from this VM i want to show a second window bound to the EditViewModel.

Comment: So i have to pass somewhere the Person to edit from the SelectedPerson in the ListViewModel, injecting it into the EditVM, and then launch the second window.

I thought that when the container tells the ViewProvider to show the window, i passed it the EditViewModel, that has to be registered if the container needs to retrieve it.

I thought the Factory class's Create method could do something like

var EVM = new EditViewModel(PersonToEdit)
ioc.register<IEditViewModel, EVM>

Comment: Why is the container 'telling' the ViewProvider to show the window? Why isn't the ListViewModel initiating the user's navigation to the edit view? Only call 'register' on your container at your compositional root - i.e. in your application startup. What is the ViewProvider by the way?

Comment: Because the ViewModel can't instantiate Views. As far as i know.
The VP is a class that has methods for instantiating the Views injecting the needed VM.

You wrote "call register" at startup, are you referring to the View?

Comment: Ok, I would strongly recommend using an MVVM framework. Trying to build an MVVM app without one will cause you considerable pain. Have a look at Caliburn.Micro - http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/

Comment: OK! Sorry but i'm new at programming and MVVM.
Thank you very much!